# Combining like objects in an array

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to analyze a group of text files (MSFTP logs) and do counts of IP addresses that have submitted bad credentials.  I think I have it worked out except I don't think that the array is passing to/from the function correctly.  As a result, I get duplicate entries if the same IP appears in multiple log files.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Function LogBadAttempt($FTPLog,$BadPassesArray)
    {
    $BadPassEx="PASS - 530"
    Foreach($Line in $FTPLog)
        {
        if ($Line -match $BadPassEx)
            {
            $IP=($Line.Split(' '))[1]
            if($BadPassesArray.IP -contains $IP)
                {
                $CurrentIP=$BadPassesArray | Where-Object {$_.IP -like $IP}
                [int]$CurrentCount=$CurrentIP.Count
                $CurrentCount++
                $CurrentIP.Count=$CurrentCount
                }else{
                $info=@{"IP"=$IP;"Count"='1'}
                $BadPass=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $info
                $BadPassesArray += $BadPass
                }
            }
        }
    return $BadPassesArray
    }
$BadPassesArray=@()
$FTPLogs = Get-Childitem \\ftpserver\MSFTPSVC1\test
$Result = ForEach ($LogFile in $FTPLogs)
    {
    $FTPLog=Get-Content ($LogFile.fullname)
    LogBadAttempt $FTPLog
    } 
$Result | Export-csv C:\Temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The result looks like...

```
Count   IP
7   209.59.17.20
20  209.240.83.135
18441   209.59.17.20
13059   200.29.3.98
```

and would like it to combine the entries for 209.59.17.20

Comment: So you have a key, the IP address. You could look for that key prior to adding a new object to your array. If you find it, retrieve the count, augment it with the new value, and off to the next round.

Comment: That was what I was attempting with the if($BadPassesArray.IP -contains $IP) part.  It works fine when I'm working on the same logfile.  When it goes on to the next logfile it's like it creates a new version of the array for that loop since doesn't see an object with the same IP value so it starts a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this *way* too complicated. Process the files in a pipeline and use a hashtable to count the occurrences of each IP address:

```psh
$BadPasswords = @{}

Get-ChildItem '\\ftpserver\MSFTPSVC1\test' | Get-Content | ? {
  $_ -like '*PASS - 530*'
} | % {
  $ip = ($_ -split ' ')[1]
  $BadPasswords[$ip]++
}

$BadPasswords.GetEnumerator() |
  select @{n='IP';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Count';e={$_.Value}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\test.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Indeed I was.  This worked perfectly (after adding an s to the $BadPassword[$ip]++).  Thanks!